# System command ( sed ) in perl

Tags: regex, perl, system, backticks

I am inside  a perl input file handle loop ,(while FH),  and I need to perform search and delete operation to another file in the that loop.

I want to perform sed operation on a file from the loop and want to capture the output of command/sed to an array variable.

something like this:

```
@flops_ = `sed '/$clkname[-2]/d' occ.txt'`
```

What should be the best way to this operation?

**occ.txt**:

```
/server/home/ramneek/kings/abc_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/abc_occ/flop1/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/def_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/def_occ/flop1/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/xyz_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/xyz_occ/flop1/Q
```

abc,def, xyz are the variables. In each parent loop, clkname[-2] will get these variables. In each loop, I need to delete respective variable matching lines.

In 1st iteration of parent while loop,
`@flops_` should look like and array separated by `\n` charachter

```
/server/home/ramneek/kings/def_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/def_occ/flop1/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/xyz_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/xyz_occ/flop1/Q
```

In 2nd iteration `@flops_` should be

```
/server/home/ramneek/kings/abc_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/abc_occ/flop1/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/xyz_occ/flop0/Q
/server/home/ramneek/kings/xyz_occ/flop1/Q
```

and so on.
TIA.

Comment: *"I am inside a perl input file handle loop"* : It seems like the question is independent of the loop? You just need to change another file (not the file you are reading from now), right?

Comment: Yeah. But I don't want to read another file  (the one I want to change) inside the parent loop.  So, I am looking for a system command to do the search and delete instead of reading file line by line.

Comment: Ok, can you give an example of the file `occ.txt` ? And from that what should be the contents of the `@flops_` array after the system call?

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is the problem with the current `sed` command? It seems it shoud work fine, right?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to do it all in perl; read the lines of the file into an array once, and in your loop use `grep` to filter out the elements you don't want.

```perl
# read the lines of occ.txt into an array 
# (or use File::Slurper or Path::Tiny to do it)
open my $focc, "<", "occ.txt" or die "Couldn't open occ.txt: $!";
my @occ = <$focc>;
chomp @occ;
close $focc;

...;

while (<$fh>) {
    ...;
    # Filter out elements
    my @flops_ = grep { not /$clkname[-2]/ } @occ;
    ...;
}
```

Comment: There might be other approaches, like a foreach loop over `@occ` that would be more appropriate than making a new array, but that depends on what you're doing with `@flops_` later.

Comment: Hi Shawn!!, Thanks it worked.